# Error in my SEARCH script

Tags: php, mysql, search, syntax

Hey guys i have an error
here it is....

> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /home/content/67/12055767/html/Welcome.php on line 13
>
> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/content/67/12055767/html/Welcome.php on line 13
> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

I made a search script. Can you please check my codes to see if you can detect an issue??

This is my PHP

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$search_output = "";
if(isset($_POST['searchquery']) && $_POST['searchquery'] != ""){
    $searchquery = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!]#i', '', $_POST['searchquery']);
    if($_POST['filter1'] == "Companies"){
        $sqlCommand = "SELECT Company_ID, Company_Name AS company FROM Company WHERE Company_Name LIKE '%$searchquery%'";
    }
    include_once("database_connect.php");
        $query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($count > 1){
        $search_output .= "<hr />$count results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />$sqlCommand<hr />";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                $id = $row->Company_ID;
            $Company_name = $row->Company_Name;
             $Image_path = $row->Image_path;
            $search_output .= "Item ID: $ $Image_path.$Company_name<br />";
                } // close while
    } else {
        $search_output = "<hr />0 results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />$sqlCommand";
    }
}
?>
```

and this is my HTML form (search box)

```
<form class="form-wrapper cf" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="searchquery" maxlength="88" placeholder="Search for Company here..." required >
        <button type="submit" name="myBtn">Search</button>
        <select name="filter1" id="filterss">
<option value="Companies" selected="selected">Companies</option>
</select>

    </form>
```

ohhh and in my conection INCLUDE i have a connection variable like so

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
```

please help me

Comment: You're mixing `mysql` and `mysqli` functions.  Your connection is made using `mysqli_connect` but in your php code you are using `mysql_` functions throughout.  Better change everywhere to use `mysqli_` functions.

Comment: BOOM that was it! how did i not see that, thanks a mil!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are connecting using `mysqli` and querying using the `mysql_*` functions. These are different libraries.

Either use `mysql_connect` which I wouldn't recommend since this library has been deprecated or use the `mysqli` functions. See here for examples: [Mysqli](https://www.php.net/mysqli).